# solution of ODE converges to zero of rhs

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let $f\in C^1(\mathbb R)$ and
$$
u'(t)=f(u(t)),~~~ u(0)=u_0 \in \mathbb R.
$$
Let $u:(t^-,t^+)\rightarrow \mathbb R$ be a maximal solution of the ODE.

*Prove:* If $f(u_0)>0$ and if there exists a root/zero $\tilde{u}\in [u_0,\infty)$ of $f$, that is, $f(\tilde{u})=0$, then $t^+=\infty$ and $\lim \limits_{t\to \infty}u(t)=\tilde{u}$ where $\tilde{u}$ is smallest zero in $[u_0,\infty)$.

I don't know how to solve this but I already know that $u$ is strictly increasing and because $f$ is in $C^1$ a solution $v$ with $v\leq \tilde{u}$ is bounded by $\tilde{u}$. Maybe this helps?

Answer (score 1):

Language notes: The "zero" of the title is a zero or root of $f$, not the actual value zero. The claim is somewhat defect. It would be necessary to first claim that $\tilde u$ is the smallest root above $u_0$, otherwise there can be two roots in the claim, the first which bounds the solution and the second one that the solution converges to and which is then indeed smallest.

---

Per the assumptions, there is a stationary point above $u_0$, $f(\tilde u)=0$, $\bar u(t)=\tilde u$ is a constant solution that no other solution can cross. Thus the solution over $[0,t^+)$ is bounded by it. That goes for any root of $f$ above $u_0$.

$f(u(t))$ can not change the sign, as that would mean to touch or cross another, constant, solution. So $u$ is increasing unconditionally an bounded above. This gives that $t_+=\infty$ and $u(t)$ reaches a limit for $t\to\infty$, or in other words is asymptotic to a constant. As ODE solution $u'(t)\to 0$ follows.

This implies that the limit point has to be a root of $f$ and thus a stationary point. There is no other root of $f$ between $u_0$ and this stationary point, as $f(u(t))>0$ everywhere.